# PC Continues fast short beep or Continues long beep

Tags: boot, memory, graphics-card, motherboard, bios

I hope I can ask this one here.

Can Anyone please help me on this. I was trying to format my pc since the bootmgr is missing.,

MY pc has a motherboard [Asus H61ME](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H61ME/). I have a Video card `GeForce GT 620` and an `ripjaws 4gb x 2 1333`. When I boot my pc, a first beep will sound for bios, then after the bios load, 
The press any key to boot on cd will be shown. when i press a key, after 5 to 10 seconds a very long beep that never stop starts. I can't realy say if its a very long beep or just a very fast short beep, I don't know what to do if i can format my pc,. wHat could be the problem on this? I don't think its on the hardware since it past through the POST. Am i right?

Comment: by the way. to the admins. there was a bug on superuser. I ask this question but my accounts is not linked on its. it should be asked by Snippets. not but user341391

Comment: The first beep basically indicates it has completed the POST. The continuous beep indicates another problem. It might be a poor connection to the hard disk, poorly inserted memory modules or cards, or an error in loading the OS. The easiest check is to see if you can get the CD to boot on another machine. Then you should re-install the memory and other internal components.

Comment: I see. if there was a poor connection or problem with memomory modules why did it past the POST test? so its possible it will past the POST even there is a hardware problem?

Answer (score 2):

A cursory search for ["asus h61me continuous beep"](https://www.google.com/search?q=asus+h61me+continuous+beep) yields plenty of results.

It indicates a hardware problem of some kind. Most commonly it seems to be memory-related. Additional possibilities, browsing through forum posts, include a bad power supply / short circuit, or bad SATA/IDE cables, or any other number of issues.

I suggest removing one component at a time until you can boot the machine successfully - that component is the trouble maker. I would start by removing one RAM module, then putting it back and removing the other. Then try disconnecting hard drives. Also try disconnecting the CD ROM drive. Then try pulling your graphics card. Perhaps you are lucky and something just needs reseated.

It is not possible to tell you exactly what the issue is based on your description, you will have to troubleshoot yourself. Do it carefully and methodically and you should be able to discover the cause. If you removed everything and the problem still occurs, see if you can borrow a power supply from a friend to test; or check the voltage in the BIOS (if it reports it) or with a voltmeter (but be careful not to short anything) to make sure it is up to par.

You could also try clearing the CMOS; it will reset the BIOS settings back to factory defaults: [instructions here](http://support.asus.com/Troubleshooting/detail.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=1&m=H61M-E&s=39&hashedid=n/a&os=&no=1723).

Also [motherboard boot failure troubleshooting from Asus](http://support.asus.com/Troubleshooting/detail.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=H61M-E&p=1&s=39&os=&hashedid=n/a&no=932).